# How to convert a JSON Image-String (not url) to a UIImage for viewing

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

Hey so I've literally been trying to solve this for a day now. So I'm desperate for an answer. What I'm trying to do its actually quite simply I have a JSON array of images in the form of a string (I think). They are not url's the image/string comes in JSON like this "GoodLogo.png" the problems is usual image from JSON come in url format. But this just says png & jpg

JSON Code I get Back:

```
(
    {
    id = 1;
    logo = "scriptslogo.png";
    name = "scripts";
},
    {
    id = 2;
    logo = "altrlogo.jpg";
    name = "Altr";
},
    {
    id = 3;
    logo = "bostonlogo.jpeg";
    name = "boston";
},
)
```

I have a variable which is an array of strings. That I put the JSON Data in.

Code:

```
    var imageList = [String]()

    let string = "https://some.url/api"

    let url = NSURL(string: string)

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)

    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let session = URLSession.shared

    let tache = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! NSArray {

            let logo = jsonObj.value(forKey: "logo") as? NSArray
            self.imageList = logo as! [String]


            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.imageTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }
    tache.resume()
```

Then all I do is try and populate the tableview but every single way that I've tried below either crashes application or doesn't show anything.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == imageTableView {

            cell = imageTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath) as! imageCell

            cell.cellImage.image = imageList[indexPath.row]


          // Iv'e tried this which I don't no if it even applies to what I'm trying to do 

          if let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: imageList[indexPath.row], options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
          let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
          cell.cellImage.image = image
        }


    }
    return cell
```

Comment: You are trying to retrieve images *from their names*. Here is a list of problems with this: long-problem-list.jpg

Comment: This way it won't work, i.e by using the image name, you must either have the image data or the image url.

Comment: ok thanks that explains why I can't get it to work

Comment: I was thinking the image data would be some how in that image string. Then I could convert it to an image. but I guess not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This**

```
let url = URL(string: "http://test.com/images/\(imageList[indexPath.row])")
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)

if let imageData = data {
    cell.cellImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
}
```